# При использовании JSESSIONID в url создаёт новую сессию

Tags: java, java-ee, tomcat, сессия

Делаю такой запрос:

```
http://qwerty.localhost:82/Server/chat/connect;8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR=05493D28DDD97308D66DAAC3DD66EAC2
```

или так:

```
http://qwerty.localhost:82/Server/chat/connect/;8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR=05493D28DDD97308D66DAAC3DD66EAC2
```

При этом id сессии(8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR) передаётся как в куках, так и в url (Так нужно для пущей безопасности, вдруг кука не поставится). Почему-то создаётся новая сессия. Почему так происходит? что не так делаю? может url не тот...

Comment: Как минимум вижу проблему в том, что если id сессии 8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR, то в URL после ";" должно быть что-то вроде "jsessionid=8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR"

Comment: @fromSPb я переопределил название сессии. Вместо JSESSIONID - 8O8488WlWWgNzAkGCFYAZyj3Bn91CR в `web.xml`

Comment: Хм. А разве список параметров в URL не должен отделятся знаком `?`

Comment: @Uraty в том и дело что это не параметр. Точнее не должен быть как параметр